# Loopback: "Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active" when begin 10 transactions at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a nodejs project using loopback and postgressql.

I got a function `handleTrade` like this, simply start the transaction with timeout 30s, query the Trade by id and do some updates:

```
async function handleTrade(id) {
  const { Trade } = app.models;
  const transaction = await Trade.beginTransaction({
    timeout: 30000 // 30 seconds
  });

  try {
    console.log(`${id} - 1`);
    const trade = await Trade.findById(id, { transaction });
    console.log(`${id} - 2`);

    if (trade) {
      // Do some updates with the trade
    }
    transaction.commit();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`${id} - 3`, e);
    transaction.rollback();
  }
}
```

I have a list of 10 ids, I want to handle all of them asynchronously and print `Done` when everything is done.

```
async function test(ids) {
  const promises = ids.map(id => handleTrade(id));
  await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log('Done');
  process.exit(0);
}

test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
```

And here's the log:

```
2 - Step 1
3 - Step 1
1 - Step 1
4 - Step 1
6 - Step 1
5 - Step 1
10 - Step 1
9 - Step 1
8 - Step 1
7 - Step 1

-- The process stuck here for 30 seconds (which is the timeout value of the transaction)

2 - Step 2
Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914ca760-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

9 - Step 2
1 - Step 2
3 - Step 2
6 - Step 2
4 - Step 2
5 - Step 2
10 - Step 2
8 - Step 2
Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914e5510-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914cce71-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914cce70-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914cf581-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914cf580-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914cf582-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914cf583-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Unhandled rejection Error: The transaction is not active: 914e5511-b804-11e8-bb6c-094b32725638
    at process.nextTick (/Users/admin/Work/NIX/nix-project/engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/transaction.js:202:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

7 - Step 2
Done
```

The processes got stuck for 30 seconds after step 1, then when transaction timeout, it return the Error `The transaction is not active`

And this only happen when I have 10 ids, if I only use 9, it run smoothly

```
test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

// Logs
2 - Step 1
4 - Step 1
5 - Step 1
9 - Step 1
7 - Step 1
8 - Step 1
6 - Step 1
1 - Step 1
3 - Step 1
2 - Step 2
4 - Step 2
9 - Step 2
8 - Step 2
1 - Step 2
5 - Step 2
7 - Step 2
6 - Step 2
3 - Step 2
Done
```

If you have any idea please help me. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the default connection pool size is 10 and you're running out of connections. Not sure how to deal with that in Loopback (never used it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try edit your datasource file.

example: my dataresources.json

old:

```
{   
  "db": {
    "url": "${DATABASE_URL}",
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "postgresql"
  }
}
```

new:

```
{
  "db": {
    "url": "${DATABASE_URL}",
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "postgresql",
    "max": 100
  }
}
```

explanation:
your problem mainly like you're running out of connection pool, this will increase it. (100 is just a example number, you can change from 0 to the max number defined in your postgresql config)

Comment: Welcome on SO, can you please explain why this edit solves the problem ? :)

Comment: @AndréDS sorry explanation in my edited answer! thanks for asking me